# Make an application work on both iPhone and iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib, nib

I would like to make it so that my iPhone app also works on iPad.

If I run it using the iPad simulator it does work, but the app doesn't show up on the iPad app store, and looks really weird.

Is it possible to create another `.xib` file for the iPad? I know how to add a new iPad `.xib` file, yet I don't know how to actually change the `RootViewController.xib` to `RootViewController_iPad.xib` if the device being used is an iPad.

I already have code for finding out if the device is an iPad, and I *don't* want to use `auto-layout`, because I would like to add different things to the view if they are using an iPad (such as using different images).

I would like to make it so that my iOS applications look good on both iPhone and iPad, and have a separate `.xib` files for each. Is it possible to change the default `.xib` file from `RootViewController` to `RootViewController_iPad`?

Comment: set your app to universal then map Your storyboards to the iphone and iPad...

Comment: use this link http://www.grahamdaley.com/computing/developing-a-universal-iphone-ipad-app/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to make an application work in both iPhone & iPad then need to follow below steps.

1. Before create an project please select universal in device section.
2. In application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: put a condition to check the device.
3. If the device is iPad then load the iPad screen and if the device is iPhone then load the iPhone screen.
4. Make sure follow the MVC pattern, So that it is easy to populate the data in both the screens.

Comment: How would I load the iPad screen?

Comment: In the application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method put a condition like check the UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM.. If it is iPad then load the screen and set to windows rootViewController.

Comment: if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) { [self.window addSubview: loadingViewcontroller.view]; }

Comment: Do you created separate class for iPad. if Yes then check the nib file connected which class.

Comment: Never mind, I have to give my file's owner a custom class `RootViewController` to make them show up.

Answer (score 1):

`@class` has no effect on outlets or actions it only tells the compiler that there is a class with the name that follows, no information about properties, or methods is included.

If you want to have a xib for the iPad don't create a new class for it, just create a new xib and set the file's owner to be the same as the what owns iPhone xib. You then need to add a check in `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` to load the correct xib.

The best option though is to tell Xcode you want a universal app when you create the project.

Comment: You can make it universal after you have created it. How would I load the iPad xib?

Comment: You should look at the documentation for `UIViewController`, specifically `-initWithNibName: bundle:`. You can check for which device type is in use and decided which nib to load based on that (nib = compiled version of xib)

Answer (score 0):

The key point here is that it must be a `UNIVERSAL application`. Its a setting when you set the app up for the 1st time. You will end up with 2 UI's (story boards or xib files).

You will have to create 2 seperate UI's for ipad and iphone. You may be able to use the main class itself for most of the code but then you have to basically put code that says

`if its iphone.....`

`if its ipad ......`